# How do you boot verbosely when booting off an alternate device?

Tags: startup

I've got a problem where boot is failing when booting off a USB stick.

So, I hold option down to choose the USB stick, but if I immediately hold down command-V after, it still boots with plain grey screen.

What do I need to do to see the boot process when booting off an option chosen device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before rebooting, open Terminal and enter `sudo nvram boot-args="-v"`. This will mean every future boot will be verbose and no keyboard shortcuts are needed. To disable, simply reverse by setting `sudo nvram boot-args=""`.

Further, from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573:

- If you're using FileVault, release the keys when you see the login window. Then log in to continue startup in single-user or verbose mode.
- If you're using a firmware password, you must turn off the password before you can start up in single-user or verbose mode.